# How to compute error rate from a decision tree?

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree, rpart

Does anyone know how to calculate the error rate for a decision tree with R?
I am using the `rpart()` function.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Assuming you mean computing error rate on the sample used to fit the model, you can use `printcp()`. For example, using the on-line example,

```
> library(rpart)
> fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis)
> printcp(fit)

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] Age   Start

Root node error: 17/81 = 0.20988

n= 81 

        CP nsplit rel error  xerror    xstd
1 0.176471      0   1.00000 1.00000 0.21559
2 0.019608      1   0.82353 0.82353 0.20018
3 0.010000      4   0.76471 0.82353 0.20018
```

The `Root node error` is used to compute two measures of predictive performance, when considering values displayed in the `rel error` and `xerror` column, and depending on the complexity parameter (first column):

- 0.76471 x 0.20988 = 0.1604973 (16.0%) is the *resubstitution error rate* (i.e., error rate computed on the training sample) -- this is roughly

  ```
  class.pred <- table(predict(fit, type="class"), kyphosis$Kyphosis)
  1-sum(diag(class.pred))/sum(class.pred)
  ```
- 0.82353 x 0.20988 = 0.1728425 (17.2%) is the *cross-validated error rate* (using 10-fold CV, see `xval` in `rpart.control()`; but see also `xpred.rpart()` and `plotcp()` which relies on this kind of measure). This measure is a more objective indicator of predictive accuracy.

Note that it is more or less in agreement with classification accuracy from `tree`:

```
> library(tree)
> summary(tree(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis))

Classification tree:
tree(formula = Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
Number of terminal nodes:  10 
Residual mean deviance:  0.5809 = 41.24 / 71 
Misclassification error rate: 0.1235 = 10 / 81
```

where `Misclassification error rate` is computed from the training sample.